# svn: E235000:assertion failed (!"URI canonicalization failed") error: git-svn died of signal 6

Tags: svn, git-svn

Getting below error while converting svn local export data into git on Ubuntu.
Please help me to resolve this error.

svn: E235000: In file '/build/subversion-owKwd0/subversion-1.13.0/subversion/libsvn_subr/dirent_uri.c' line 1684: assertion failed (!"URI canonicalization failed")
error: git-svn died of signal 6